# Magento 1.9 / OpenMage - New Order Confirmation Email Not Being Sent

Tags: magento-1.9, email, openmage

We have a fresh Magento installation 1.9.2.4. Confirmation emails for new orders are not being sent. After reading [this thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent), it's clear that Magento now queues all new order emails. That thread has many people suggesting to just override the queue - not a good solution. Queueing emails was done for performance. Nevertheless, our order emails are not sending.

Considerations:

1. We are using SendGrid for SMTP. This works ok, see point 3.
2. Cron is set up, and is running successfully.
3. Invoice Emails, which are sent instantly do send, and are received OK.

Emails are being added to the queue, as can be seen in the table...

```
SELECT message_id, created_at, processed_at FROM core_email_queue ORDER BY message_id DESC LIMIT 2;
+------------+---------------------+--------------+
| message_id | created_at          | processed_at |
+------------+---------------------+--------------+
|         42 | 2017-01-08 12:04:49 | NULL         |
|         41 | 2017-01-08 12:04:48 | NULL         |
+------------+---------------------+--------------+
```

And they're seemingly being processed:

```
mysql> SELECT message_id, created_at, processed_at FROM core_email_queue ORDER BY message_id DESC LIMIT 2;
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| message_id | created_at          | processed_at        |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|         42 | 2017-01-08 12:04:49 | 2017-01-08 12:05:02 |
|         41 | 2017-01-08 12:04:48 | 2017-01-08 12:05:02 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

However, in the SendGrid log, there's no email had been sent.

So the logic to add it to the queue is seemingly working, and the cron logic that processes and presumably sends the email is also seemingly working, but no email is being sent or received.

Another [thread here appears to be describing a similar (possibly identical) problem](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120489/order-emails-marked-as-sent-but-not-received).

--
EDIT

Interestingly, I tried to run the cron.php manually, and getting this message:

```
vagrant$ /usr/bin/php cron.php 
sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found
sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found
```

Which is very strange as we have it setup to use SendGrid SMTP.

Comment: To update. So far, I can say with quite a high level of confidence that this is not due to a missing mbstring extension as an answer to the almost identical question suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as an update and to answer my own question, I never found a fix for this. It seems to be an issue with the client's web-server.

EDIT: Found the issue. The webhost was blocking access to sendmail. How, why, no idea? SMTP solution below solved it.

Instead, I installed the [Magento 1 SMTP Pro Extension by Ashley Schroder](https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension) which I can also confirm works as expected with [OpenMage LTS](https://www.openmage.org/).